# Input Box Current number validation

Tags: html

If I type a phone number in a input box. Example 017xxxxxx.
Then submit button will work. if I type 019 or other number in first 3 character. Submit button will not work.i mean Validation input box for 017xxxxxxxx . If someone one type without 017. submit button will not work .how can I do that?

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question (and to share the results of that research in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `javascript` `regex` (regular expressions).

Set the `submit button` to be `disabled` in the beginning by setting `disabled="disabled"` in its tag. Use the `keyup()` function on the button to get every change in the text field.

Then use the `regex` to check if the `input value` meets the criteria. If it does `enable the button`, otherwise `disable it/keep it disabled`.

**Note:** The regular expression used here ( '^017([0-9]+){6}$' ) will test any input to start with 017 and make sure it has at least six more numbers.

**Here is the code example:**

```js
function check(e)
{
   var regex = RegExp('^017([0-9]+){6}$', 'i');
   if(regex.test(e.value))
   {
       document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
   }
   else
   {
       document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
   }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="inputTel" onkeyup="check(this)" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit me" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried `<input type="tel">` instead of `<input type="number">` ?
You can take a look:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: Not like that friend. Validation input box for  017xxxxxxxx . If someone one type without 017 submit button will not work